# Is there a more detailed way to debug SFSpeechRecognizer?

Tags: swift, sfspeechrecognizer

**Updated info below, and new code**

I am trying to incorporate SFSpeechRecognizer into my app, and the errors/results I am getting from three pre-recorded audiofiles aren't enough for me to figure out what's going on. From the results I am getting I can't figure out what's wrong, and info via Google is sparse.

The code where I loop through three files is at the bottom. Here are the responses I get for my three audio files. I've made sure in each file to speak loudly and clearly, yet I still get:  No speech detected or no text returned.

> SS-X-03.m4a : There was an error: Optional(Error
> Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1110 "No speech detected"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No speech detected})
>
> SS-X-20221125000.m4a : There was an error: Optional(Error
> Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1110 "No speech detected"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No speech detected})
>
> SS-X-20221125001.m4a : (there is some text here if I set
> request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition to false)

My code:

```
func findAudioFiles(){
        let fm = FileManager.default
        var aFiles : URL
        
        print ("\(urlPath)")
        do {
            let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsPath)

            let filteredInterestArray1 = items.filter({$0.hasSuffix(".m4a")})
            let filteredInterestArray2 = filteredInterestArray1.filter({$0.contains("SS-X-")})
            let sortedItems = filteredInterestArray2.sorted()
            
            for item in sortedItems {
                audioFiles.append(item)
            }

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("goAndRead"), object: nil, userInfo: myDic)

        } catch {
            print ("\(error)")
        }
}

@objc func goAndRead(){
    audioIndex += 1
    if audioIndex != audioFiles.count {
    let fileURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: documentsPath + "/" + audioFiles[audioIndex], isDirectory: false)
    transcribeAudio(url: fileURL, item: audioFiles[audioIndex])
    }
}

func requestTranscribePermissions() {
    SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { [unowned self] authStatus in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if authStatus == .authorized {
                print("Good to go!")
            } else {
                print("Transcription permission was declined.")
            }
        }
    }
}



func transcribeAudio(url: URL, item: String) {
    guard let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US")) else {return}
    let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: url)
    if !recognizer.supportsOnDeviceRecognition { print ("offline not available") ; return   }
     if !recognizer.isAvailable { print ("not available") ; return   }
    request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
    request.shouldReportPartialResults = true

    recognizer.recognitionTask(with: request) {(result, error) in
        guard let result = result else {
            print("\(item) : There was an error: \(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }

        if result.isFinal {
            print("\(item) : \(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("goAndRead"), object: nil, userInfo: self.myDic)
        }
    }
}
```

*Updated info*
*It appears that I was calling SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest too often, and before I completed the first request. Perhaps I need to create a new instance of SFSpeechRecognizer? Unsure.*

*Regardless I quickly/sloppily adjusted the code to only run it once the previous instance returned its results.*

*The results were much better, except one audio file still came up as no results. Not an error, just no text.*

*This file is the same as the previous file, in that I took an audio recording and split it in two. So the formats and volumes are the same.*

*So I still need a better way to debug this, to find out what it going wrong with that file.*

Comment: Have you seen apple's demo on [recognizing speech](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/recognizing_speech_in_live_audio)? Is there a way to config the analyzing language?

Comment: Going through it, there's only one additional property there, which didn't change it. Found a small error in the "locale" but that wasn't it.

Comment: Found some of the issues, updated OP

Comment: Further.. Good luck!